# Can I pass an Account via an Intent to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, account

Is it possible to pass an Android Account object from one activity to another via an Intent?  If so, how?  Is it good programming practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean `android.accounts.Account` then 'Yes', as it implements `Parcelable`, you can pass it as an extra of an `Intent` using the `putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)` method of `Intent`.

Whether it's good programming practice or not...that depends entirely on why you want to do it and what the `Activity` that receives it will do with it.

Comment: @Squonk - I've been looking all over for how to do this... do you think you can update your answer with a code sample? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can send in the account to other activities through **Intent**

First get the account if the user is already signed in

```
GoogleSignInAccount account;
account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
```

Then pass the account as an Extra in the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ReceiverActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ACCOUNT",account);
            startActivity(intent);
```

And in the ReceiverActivity

```
GoogleSignInAccount account =getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ACCOUNT");
```

Then you can get other details from the user's profile like

```
String personName = account.getDisplayName();
            String personGivenName = account.getGivenName();
            String personFamilyName = account.getFamilyName();
            String personEmail = account.getEmail();
            String personId = account.getId();
            Uri personPhoto = account.getPhotoUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a code sample, and explain a little what exactly you are using this passing for ?

You might want to optimize the flow of your application, in order to process the account info directly, and create the account object when you need it.

Comment: Sure, I've got an application with a series of activities that interact with a server through a series of restful api's.  The server requires oauth2 authentication.  I'm caching the token in the account manager and want to fetch the token from the account manager as needed.  By passing the account around, it makes retrieving auth tokens easy.